# Why is CreateGlobalFunctionBinding ( N, V, D ) algorithm setting value twice?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2017

I cannot understand some steps of this [CreateGlobalFunctionBinding ( N, V, D )](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-createglobalfunctionbinding) EcmaScript algorithm.

Could you explain me steps 5, 7 and 9 in this algorithm? I cannot figure out the sense of 9 step because of 7 step. Why is value V setting twice?

Please, help :)